# Image View change size for iPhone Screen Size using AutoLayout Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, storyboard, autolayout

I have an `Image View` that I want the height and width to be changed based on screen size:

- iPhone 6 Plus **414x414**
- iPhone 6 **375x375**
- iPhone 5s **320x320**

Any constraints I put on the `Image View` in the Storyboard seem to hardcode it in (i.e. constrain height and width), so it'll work for one size but not all the others.

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

**UPDATE**

I've got a custom table view cell `TableViewCellTwo`, and it sits inside of the table view controller `TableViewController`.

**TableViewController.m**

```
TableViewCellTwo *api2Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourAPI2Cell"];

api2Cell.labelHeadline.text = user;
api2Cell.labelDescription.text = cap;
api2Cell.labelPublished.text = date;

self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600.0;


// SDWebImage
if ([data.images count] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Images Count: %lu", (unsigned long)data.images.count);
}
else {
    Images *imageLocal = [data.images objectAtIndex:0];
    StandardResolution *standardResolutionLocal = [imageLocal.standard_resolution objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", standardResolutionLocal.url];

    __weak TableViewCellTwo *wcell = api2Cell;
    [wcell.imageView
     sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"320x180.gif"]
     ];
}

return api2Cell;
```

}

Comment: dont use height or width constrains, use "pin to super view" ones.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Use pin to super view of zero on the left and right then?

Comment: Yes, you always need constrains to define its size, and another to define its position, in this case if you pin left, right, top and bottom it should work, or if you want to have SPECIFIC sizes, for those screens, you can modify them programatically detecting the current screen size

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what I would use as the value for the top and bottom pin.  I already have vertical spacing between the label above it, and then bottom spacing to container margin from the bottom of the image view?

Comment: Basically when I clear all constraints from the image view: if I put 0 as a pin for top, bottom, left, right... its still doing the same thing (cutting the image off on the right for iPhone 6 compared to iPhone 6 Plus)

Comment: then you might have issues with its view mode, make sure its set to aspect fit / fill

Comment: View - Mode - should be which of the two: Aspect Fit or Aspect Fill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to have your image view pinned to the two sides of the view (with 0 length constraints), and give it an aspect ratio of 1:1. If you do that, plus add a vertical constraint to the label above it, then it will work properly (there should be no constraint to the bottom of the view).

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Per your answer: I added a vertical constraint to the label above, then pinned the 2 sides (left constrained to margins checked), then added an aspect ratio of 1:1.  Just wondering why there wouldn't need to be a constraint to the bottom of the view?  Right now the cell is too short vertically because it isn't making room for all of the items in the cell (of which the image view is the last in the vertical stack).

Comment: Also, does it matter what my image view's height and width are even though I'm not setting them as constraints?  Right now the image view is just 320x320.

Comment: By pinning the view to the sides of the view, that gives it a width that's specific for any particular screen size. So, since the width is set, and you have an aspect ratio set, that sets the height. You wouldn't normally need a constraint to the bottom, but if this is in a table view cell, then maybe that would be good to have, so the cell automatically adjusts its height.

Comment: That all makes perfect sense I think.  But for some reason, the Image View is still staying 320x320 (or whatever width and height its at in the Size Inspector) no matter what.  Even tho the width and height aren't set as constraints, they are just whatever I dragged the image view out as.  Any ideas on what else I could check that would be making it not work properly?

Comment: I added some extra info in my original question, just in case it helps!  Also, I'm pulling in the images from an API, which standard resolution is 612x612.

Comment: Do you mean it stays 320x320 no matter what size iPhone (or simulator) you're using? There's nothing in your additional information that helps with the problem. The problem is most likely in the constraints in the storyboard.

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant.  It stays 320x320 no matter what size iPhone simulator I'm using.  I just added the additional information in case there was something overriding the storyboard in my code or something I was missing.